# How to define a correct edge definition for this recursive function?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Solution if anyone is interested:

```
f :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
f [] = []
f [x] = []
f (x:y:xs)
 | x < y = max x y : f (y:xs)
 | otherwise = f (y:xs)
```

sample input:

```
f [1,3,2,4,3,4,5] == [3,4,4,5]
f [5,10,6,11,7,12] == [10,11,12]
```

Updated code:

```
f [] = []
f [x] = [x]
f (x:y:xs)
 | x < y = max x y : f (y:xs)
 | otherwise = f (y:xs)
```

The problem is that it outputs the last number twice:

```
f [5,10,6,11,7,12] == [10,11,12,12]
```

> Old content below

I am writing a function that takes a list and returns the elements that are larger than the previous one. I came up with this, but the problem is that when it reaches the last element, xs !! 0 doesn't exist, thus the error. How can I define a correct exit point in this case?

my code:

```
f :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
f [] = []
f (x:xs) = max x (xs !! 0) : f xs
```

error:

```
[3,3,4,4,4,5,*** Exception: Prelude.!!: index too large
```

Comment: Base case goes first

Comment: Don't use indexing, use pattern matching instead for that case. You'll have to separately define what you want to happen for a singleton list.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard I edited the question, still gives me the error.

Comment: @RobinZigmond how would I use pattern matching in this case? (sorry, I'm a beginner) How can I tell GHCI that I'm defining a case for a singleton list?

Comment: `[x]`<-- will pattern match against a singleton list.

Comment: I mean your three cases should be `[]`, `[x]` and `(x:y:xs)` - for lists of 0, 1 and 2+ elements respectively.

Comment: @RobinZigmond
greaters [] = []
greaters [x] = [x]
greaters (x:y:xs) = max x y : greaters xs

I made this, but this is not working correctly. For example, If i run it with [1,2,3,4,5] it only outputs [2,4,5] because it doesn't matches the 3. This is why I was trying to use head or !! 0

Comment: Updated the original question for readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't always going to add a new element to the result; sometimes you'll add nothing.

```
f :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
f [] = []
f [x] = [x]
f (x:y:xs) = _  -- what goes here?
```

For your recursive case, there are two possibilities:

1. If `x < y`,  you'll add `y` to the result.
2. Otherwise, you won't add `y` to the result. In fact, you won't add *anything*.

In either case, you need to include `y` in the recursive call, not just `xs`, so that on the next iteration, `y` will be the first element to be compared to the one after *it*.

I leave it as an exercise to implement the above logic as your recursive case.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I made some changes to the code, which you can see edited in the original question. The only problem is that it outputs the last number twice. Why is this?

Comment: got it, I just wrote f [x] = [] !